# How to trigger Windows for user credentials prompt?

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-identity

I'm looking for an idea/solution that works on both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

For critical actions in my WPF application I want the user to explicitly authenticate again against the operating system. On the web exist many custom solutions like NuGet packages that look like a Windows prompt that asks the user for the password. Like the one that shows up, if you try to access network shares you are not authenticated for.

I do not want to use those custom solutions, I want to use those provided by operating system, if any.

In detail I'm looking for something like that:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
bool authenticated = [WindowsAPI].Authenticate(identity);
if(authenticated)
{
    //do critical action
}
```

Does such a WindowsAPI exist?

**EDIT:** The WindowsAPI should have an own UI and, in best case, validates the credentials and does not store any.

Comment: Try `CredUIPromptForCredentialsA` with pinvoke : [Doc](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduipromptforcredentials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall answer is: No, there does not exist a Windows API that includes an own UI and additionally validates the entered credentials.

In short, I used `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` that pops up a configurable operation system dialog to enter credentials, `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer` to unpack credentials and `LogonUser` to verify the unpacked credentials. At the end clear the memory allocated by `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` using `CoTaskMemFree`.

MS Docs:

- [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforwindowscredentialsa)
- [CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credunpackauthenticationbuffera)
- [LogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera)
- [CoTaskMemFree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemfree)

P/Invoke Docs:

- [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.creduipromptforwindowscredentials)
- [CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui.credunpackauthenticationbuffer)
- [LogonUser](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LogonUser.html)
- [CoTaskMemFree](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/CoTaskMemFree.html)

Answer (score 1):

`bool authenticated = [WindowsAPI].Authenticate(identity);`
Should it ask user to enter the login and password one more time?

You can try to use Windows API [LogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera). However it does not supply UI to collect user name and password. You can try to create a dialog form with two textboxes by your own.

There is `IPublicClientApplication` and `AcquireToken*` methods. Please check the [AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.ipublicclientapplication.acquiretokenbyintegratedwindowsauth?view=azure-dotnet). 
However it works with AzureAD to get the token so I'm not sure does it fit to your requirements.

Comment: Yes, the API should have an own UI.