# How do I connect to Microsoft Teams with the Credential parameter with Powershell in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, credentials

I can connect to Microsoft Teams by running the following commands in Powershell, respectively.

```
Get-Credential
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential
```

How can I do these commands in C#?

This C# code did not work

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Connect-MicrosoftTeams").AddParameter("Credential").AddParameter("Get-Credential").Invoke();
```

Running it in Powershell opens the Login window. but not opened in C# code

Comment: See this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986728/how-to-trigger-windows-for-user-credentials-prompt

Comment: I think I made a mistake while running the powershell script in C#. Normally the powershell script I write is running